# Calculating average without considering missing values in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a dataset with many missing values as -999. Part of the data is

```
input.txt
30
-999
10
40
23
44
-999
-999
31
-999
54
-999 
-999
-999
-999
-999
-999
-999 and so on
```

I would like calculate the average in each 6 rows interval without considering the missing values.

Desire output is

```
ofile.txt
29.4
42.5
-999
```

While I am trying with this

```
awk '!/\-999/{sum += $1; count++} NR%6==0{print count ? (sum/count) : count;sum=count=0}' input.txt
```

it is giving

```
29.4
42.5
0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why, if you're discounting `-999` values, you'd think that `-999` was a better choice than zero for the average of the third group. In the first two groups, the `-999` values contribute to neither the sum nor the count, so an argument could be made that zero is a better choice.

However, it may be that you want `-999` to represent a "lack of value" (which would certainly be the case where there were no values in a group). If that's the case, you can just ouput `-999` rather than `count` in your original code:

```
awk '!/\-999/{sm+=$1;ct++} NR%6==0{print ct?(sm/ct):-999;sm=ct=0}' input.txt
```

Even if you decide that zero *is* a better answer, I'd still make that explicit rather than outputting the count variable itself:

```
awk '!/\-999/{sm+=$1;ct++} NR%6==0{print ct?(sm/ct):0;sm=ct=0}' input.txt
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I really need -999 because there are many 0 values in the data. So if I use 0 in stead of -999, them those existing 0 values will be treated as missing.

Comment: Dear paxdiablo, can you please suggest me if I want to format the output values in the above script up to three decimal points?

Comment: @Kayan, probably should be a different question but have a look at `awk 'BEGIN{printf "%.3f\n", 3.14159}'` which gives `3.142`. In other words, use `printf` rather than `print` (and make sure you add your own newlines, `print` does that but `printf` does not).