# Calculating average in irregular intervals without considering missing values in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I have a dataset with many missing values as -999. Part of the data is

```
input.txt
30
-999
10
40
23
44
-999
-999
31
-999
54
-999 
-999
-999
-999
-999
-999
10
23
2
5
3
8
8
7
9
6
10
and so on
```

I would like calculate the average in each 5,6,6 rows interval without considering the missing values.

Desire output is

```
ofile.txt
25.75   (i.e. consider first 5 rows and take average without considering missing values, so (30+10+40+23)/4)
43      (i.e. consider next 6 rows and take average without considering missing values, so (44+31+54)/3)
-999    (i.e. consider next 6 and take average without considering missing values. Since all are missing, so write as a missing value -999)
8.6     (i.e. consider next 5 rows and take average (10+23+2+5+3)/5)
8     (i.e. consider next 6 rows and take average)
```

I can do if it is regular interval (lets say 5) with this

```
awk '!/\-999/{sum += $1; count++} NR%5==0{print count ? (sum/count) :-999;sum=count=0}' input.txt
```

I asked a similar question with regular interval here [Calculating average without considering missing values in shell script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307267/calculating-average-without-considering-missing-values-in-shell-script) But here I am asking the solution for irregular intervals.

Comment: while well structured Q, your math examples are scaring me ;-) : `consider next 6 rows and take average (44+31+54)/3)` . don't you need 6 values and divide by 6. Only your 8.6 example seems correct. Good luck

Comment: @shellter Thank you. It should neither consider the missing values nor count them as a contributor.

Comment: Ah, got it. Sorry, I didn't read your Q closely enough. Good luck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating average without considering missing values in shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32307267/calculating-average-without-considering-missing-values-in-shell-script)

Comment: @agc It is not duplicate. There it was regular interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With **AWK**

```
awk -v f="5" 'f&&f--&&$0!=-999{c++;v+=$0} NR%17==0{f=5;r++} 
!f&&NR%17!=0{f=6;r++} r&&!c{print -999;r=0} r&&c{print v/c;r=v=c=0}
END{if(c!=0)print v/c}' input.txt
```

**Output**

```
25.75
43
-999
8.6
8
```

**Breakdown**

```
f&&f--&&$0!=-999{c++;v+=$0} #add valid values and increment count
NR%17==0{f=5;r++} #reset to 5,6,6 pattern 
!f&&NR%17!=0{f=6;r++} #set 6 if pattern doesnt match
r&&!c{print -999;r=0} #print -999 if no valid values
r&&c{print v/c;r=v=c=0} #print avg
END{
 if(c!=0) #print remaining values avg
  print v/c
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ cat tst.awk
function nextInterval(  intervals) {
    numIntervals = split("5 6 6",intervals)
    intervalsIdx = (intervalsIdx % numIntervals) + 1
    return intervals[intervalsIdx]
}

BEGIN {
    interval = nextInterval()
    noVal = -999
}

$0 != noVal {
    sum += $0
    cnt++
}

++numRows == interval {
    print (cnt ? sum / cnt : noVal)
    interval = nextInterval()
    numRows = sum = cnt = 0
}

$ awk -f tst.awk file
25.75
43
-999
8.6
8
```